# Why does my loop run twice?

Tags: java, animation, for-loop, applet

I'm trying to run basic animations, and all of the problems in my program is rooted in one of my loops running twice instead of once. I've isolated the problem here:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    public class PrinnyTest extends Applet{
public void init()
{
    setSize(600, 550);
}

public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    Image img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "http://www.clipartqueen.com/image-files/cats-head.png");
    for(int y = 600;y>=20; y--)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 550);
        g.drawImage(img, 40, y, null);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {}
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, it moves the image to the top but then resets the position and starts the loop over again. I feel like the answer is staring me right in the face, but for some reason I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` in Event Dispatch Thread isn't recommended. Use swing `javax.swing.Timer` or something like that.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. ..

Comment: .. 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: General tips: 1) Never try to load resources (such as images) within a paint method! Such image loading should be done in the `init()` method. 2) Remove `setSize(600, 550);` from the `init()` method. The applet's size is set by the HTML that loads it. The applet should not try to 2nd guess the space it has been provided. 3) `g.drawImage(img, 40, y, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img, 40, y, this);` since an `Applet` implements `ImageObserver`. 4) `g.setColor(Color.white);  g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 550);` would better be achieved by setting the BG color to white in the constructor, then..

Comment: .. calling `super.paint(g);` as the first thing in the overriden paint method. 5) Always use `@Override` notation when changing methods, as it provides compile time checking of method signatures. 6) And like mentioned by @zakki earlier, don't ever call for a `Thread.sleep(..)` in a paint method. This is not the correct way to go about animation.